# Finding package stored in R

Tags: r

I would like to install the package `lefse`, but it is not available now.

However, I already installed on my laptop before. Now, I want to find it in the library, then copy to another computer.

So far, I only know this function to go directly to the library folder `.libPaths()`.

Does anyone know this? or can you download that package online? please help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ican you try with `snashot` i.e. 
`base_url <- "http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/";


when <- "2019-09-02";



options(repos = list(CRAN = paste0(base_url, when)))'


install.packages("lefse")`

Comment: From a `bash`-like shell, a very slow method might be `find / -name lefse -type d`. Again, *slow*, but it is the only sure-fire way that I can recommend for your to guarantee finding it (if it exists).

Comment: This package is pretty old.  Main issue is with the Rcpp version which is not getting compatible with this one

Comment: @akrun it is asking me to install some packages that i have to install. I did install some. Only this `SDMTools` I can not download it. I got this error

Comment: * installing *source* package 'SDMTools' ...
** package 'SDMTools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'SDMTools'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anh/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/SDMTools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Anh/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0qQLrp/downloaded_packages/SDMTools_1.1-221.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: For me SDMTools got installed, but it was the last step with Rccp incompatibility that caused problem

Comment: yeah, I ran codes above, and 3 packages that I have to install. Now, only SDMTools need to be installed, but somehow it can not be done here

Comment: It seems to be stupid but I did get the lefse folder from my laptop, i copied to the PC :D. it was solved now